# Optimization of horizontal lines

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, geometry

I have run into an optimization problem which I think is a combination of known problems, but I can't seem to find the right algorithms.

The problem concerns adding a certain number of horizontal lines across a space with obstacles, and minimizing the length of the lines. There are constraints on the number of lines, the spacing between them and the spacing between the lines and boundary of the space.

***edit***
 An example of what the input and output could look like to calrify the problem:

input:

- The number of lines that should be added (2 in the exaple below)
- The minimal allowed value for the spacing shown in the picture
- The minimal allowed value for the spacing from the lines to the edges of the  space
- geometric data containing the edges and obstacles

Design parameters are the Y values of the start points

Output:

- coordinates of the optimal lines

If a solution with normal lines can not be found that satisfy the constraints, a line can "skip over" an obstacle, but when that happens, an extra line which is longer than the  skipped distance needs to be added under or over the obstacle (see example).

[image]

I have looked into turning the space into a grid and using path finding algorithms like A*. I have also looked at Linear programming algorithms such as the simplex method, but I don't really know how to represent the problem, especially the "skipping" part.

Any help regarding how to represent the problem or pointers towards similar problems or useful algorithms would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Embed the picture

Comment: Are you given a list of lines with specific length that you can use? If not, how is the overlap determined?

Comment: LP is probably out of the question, but a MIP model should be possible. Binary variables allow us to implement some kinds of if-then constructs.

Comment: I'm not given a list of lines with specfic lengths, the overlap is however a constant value meaning the extra line is the width of the obstacle plus two times this constant value.

Comment: What does "minimizing the length of the lines" mean?  (If we can control their length, why not just set all their lengths to 0?)  It's also unclear what "there are constraints on the number of lines" means -- it sounds like you are asking us to break something into a number of lines...?

Comment: Sorry for beeing unclear, i'm not very used to wording these types of problems. The lines are required to go from the left side of the space to the right side (unless there is a need to "skip" over an obstacle).

What i mean by constraints on the number of lines is simply: "There should be X lines" which i think is what you sugested.

Feel free to ask followup questions if this isn't clear either :)

Comment: what exactly is input? add example of input and wanted output as your current state of OP is not clear to me at all and the text just confuses in comparison to that image (but it is possible it is just me). Once we declare the problem clearly then we can try to solve it or hint how to do it...

Comment: Thank you for the input! I will try to revise the OP

Comment: Looking better, but I can't tell if "Design parameters are the Y values of the start points" means that these Y values are the desired *outputs* (as I currently understand it, they are, and they are the *only* outputs, since the X co-ords of lines are determined by given margins around the outside of obstacles and the inside of the containing rectangle) or inputs.  If so, it would be clearest to change this to "Desired outputs are the Y values of all lines" and delete "Output: co-ords of the optimal lines".

Comment: Does "The minimal allowed value for the spacing from the lines to the edges of the space" mean vertical spacing from the top and bottom of the space?  Also, does "minimizing the length of the lines" (your apparent objective) really mean "minimizing the vertical extent occupied by the lines"?

Comment: Finally, if indeed you want to minimise the vertical extent occupied by the lines: How to trade this off against extra lines required by going "through" obstacles?  (Side question: Are these extra lines also required to obey the minimal between-line spacing?  If so, they will rarely be advantageous...)  A nice way is to specify a cost function hC + e, where h is the total height (vertical extent), e is the total number of extra lines, and C is a constant factor to control the tradeoff between them: then the objective is to minimise the overall cost for given C.

Comment: Another potentially complicating factor is that a 2nd obstacle could prevent the placement of a line directly beneath a 1st obstacle, since that line needs to be wider; so: how much wider?  In fact, what should happen if 2 or more obstacles block a line?

Comment: Getting closer. Just a silly question but I still miss description what the line represents. It should be approximation of obstacle? or free space?  or what? the image has only 2 "valid" lines one goes through obstacle other is not but that can be due booth spacing and different meaning of lines  so I do not know hence cant help as this is fundamental info for your task. Also the extra line is wanted or not?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers!

Just by trying to answer all your questions i have realized the problem as stated, is too hard to fit the scope of the task and ill mark this as answered.

Il try to answer your questions to provide som clossure though.

Regarding what the problem represents, It has to do with structural design. The obstacles are holes and the lines are beams.

Regarding minimizing the vertical extent occupied, i dont think that matters so much. A better way to select the best line is probably to give some benefit to lines close to the center of their interval.